Can we place a Ninja Foodie XL 6 in 1 convection oven where our conventional oven has been?
Our in-the-wall oven has died.  We never really used it anyway.  We have a Ninja Foodie 6 in 1 air fryer/convection oven that we use regularly. Can we place it in the spot where our built-in oven has been located?  It would have at least 6 inches clearance on all sides and open to the front.

Does the "spot where your oven has been" provide adequate clearances for the portable oven you wish to place there? If so, likely with a bit of re-wiring to supply the correct voltage, you can put it there. If not, you can't.
Countertop portable ovens are generally not designed for zero-clearance installation. 6" may well be enough or it may not - check the owner's manual for the oven. Top clearance might be a sticking point.
